# xslt apply-template with 2 different XML files with same structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have 2 xml files for French and English languages to generate a HTML. I'm accessing the content of English XML using xslt document() function.

XML 1 French

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Comptes</group-name>
    </group-container>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Paiements</group-name>
    </group-container>
        <group-container>
        <group-name>Cartes</group-name>
    </group-container>  
</Root>
```

XML 2 English

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Accounts</group-name>
    </group-container>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Payments</group-name>
    </group-container>
        <group-container>
        <group-name>cards</group-name>
    </group-container>  
</Root>
```

My XSLT is

```
<xsl:variable name="en-xml-analytics">
    <xsl:value-of select="//path to XML 2 English "/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <div class="first-level-inner">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./group-container" mode="first-level" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group-container" mode="first-level">
    <div>
        <span>
            <xsl:for-each select="document($en-xml-analytics)/Root/group-container">
                <xsl:attribute name="data-webanalytics">menunavigation.<xsl:value-of select="./group-name" />
                </xsl:attribute>            
            </xsl:for-each>             
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="group-name" />
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output

```
<div class="first-level-inner">
   <div><span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.Accounts"><span>Comptes</span></span></div>
   <div><span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.Payments"><span>Paiements</span></span></div>
   <div><span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.cards"><span>Cartes</span></span></div>
</div>
```

How to get values from both XML files inside same `<div>`

Comment: How are the French and English values related, by the position of the `group-container` in the root element?

Comment: And which XSLT processor is that exactly? These days with Saxon 10 and XSLT 3 this looks like a nice job for `for-each-pair` or `xsl:merge`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, yes the position of  ``` group-container``` is exactly the same in French and English and the processor is   ```<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> ```

Comment: That is your XSLT code, which software do you use to run that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 with higher-order function support (e.g. Saxon HE 10 or later, Saxon 9.8 PE or EE or later, Saxon-JS 2, Altova XML 2017 R3 and later) this might be a job for `for-each-pair`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:param name="en-doc">
<Root>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Accounts</group-name>
    </group-container>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Payments</group-name>
    </group-container>
        <group-container>
        <group-name>cards</group-name>
    </group-container>  
</Root>    
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:merge" as="element(div)">
    <xsl:param name="container1" as="element(group-container)"/>
    <xsl:param name="container2" as="element(group-container)"/>
    <div>
        <span data-web-analytics="menunavigation.{$container2/group-name}">
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="$container1/group-name" />
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>    
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="Root">
      <div class="first-level-inner">
          <xsl:sequence select="for-each-pair(group-container, $en-doc/Root/group-container, mf:merge#2)"/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Instead of the inlined data you could of course use e.g. `<xsl:param name="en-doc" select="doc('english-data.xml')"/>`.

For your original code it should work to use position stored in a variable e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="group-container" mode="first-level">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <div>
        <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.{document($en-xml-analytics)/Root/group-container[$pos]/group-name}">         
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="group-name" />
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think it is Saxon Professional Edition. Not completely sure. Unfortunately XSLT 3.0 is not supported. Can you help me with how to do this with XSLT 2.0 please.

Comment: @user2628187, I already did that at the end of the answer.

Comment: I'm kinda lost with the second level and not getting the required results. Could you please help me how to handle if I have second level? Since this is closed, I've opened a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452580/xslt-with-2-different-xml-files-with-same-structure-and-multiple-levels