# xslt with 2 different XML files with same structure and multiple levels

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have 2 xml files for French and English languages to generate a HTML. I'm accessing the content of English XML using xslt document() function. I have a problem with second level `<group-title>/<title-name>`

XML1 French

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Comptes</group-name>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>Consulter des comptes</title-name>                  
        </group-title>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>Comptes</title-name>                   
        </group-title>
    </group-container>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Paiements</group-name>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>Historique</title-name>
        </group-title>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>Nouveau compte</title-name>
        </group-title>
    </group-container>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Cartes</group-name>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>Créer un virement</title-name>
        </group-title>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>Virements</title-name>
        </group-title>
    </group-container>  
</Root>
```

XML2 English

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Accounts</group-name>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>open new account</title-name>                  
        </group-title>
        <group-title>
            <title-name> linked accounts</title-name>                   
        </group-title>
    </group-container>
    <group-container>
        <group-name>Payments</group-name>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>History</title-name>
        </group-title>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>New Payment</title-name>
        </group-title>
    </group-container>
        <group-container>
        <group-name>cards</group-name>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>Make a Payment</title-name>
        </group-title>
        <group-title>
            <title-name>statement</title-name>
        </group-title>
    </group-container>  
</Root>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="en-xml-analytics">
    <xsl:value-of select="//path to XML 2 English "/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <div class="first-level-inner">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./group-container" mode="first-level" />
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./group-container" mode="second-level" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group-container" mode="first-level">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <div>
        <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.{document($en-xml-analytics)/Root/group-container[$pos]/group-name}">         
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="group-name" />
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group-container" mode="second-level">
    <div class="second-level-inner">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="group-title" mode="title" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group-title" mode="title">
    <xsl:variable name="pos1" select="position()"/>
    <h5>
        <xsl:value-of select="title-name" />
    </h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.{document($en-xml-analytics)/Root/group-container[$pos1]/group-title[$pos1]/title-name}"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output

```
<div class="first-level-inner">
    <div>
        <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.Accounts">
            <span>Comptes</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.Payments">
            <span>Paiements</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.Cards">
            <span>Cartes</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="second-level-inner">
    <h5>Consulter des comptes</h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.open new account"/>
    <h5>Comptes</h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.linked accounts"/>
</div>
<div class="second-level-inner">
    <h5>Historique</h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.History"/>
    <h5>Nouveau compte</h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.New Payment"/>
</div>
<div class="second-level-inner">
    <h5>Créer un virement</h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.Make a Payment"/>
    <h5>Virements</h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.statement"/>
</div>
```

I can get the first level / successfully with `position()`. However I'm lost with second level position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the outer position on as a parameter e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="group-container" mode="second-level">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <div class="second-level-inner">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="group-title" mode="title">
           <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos" tunnel="yes"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

plus

```
<xsl:template match="group-title" mode="title">
    <xsl:param name="pos" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pos1" select="position()"/>
    <h5>
        <xsl:value-of select="title-name" />
    </h5>
    <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.{document($en-xml-analytics)/Root/group-container[$pos]/group-title[$pos1]/title-name}"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of passing the outer position on you could also opt to pass the `document($en-xml-analytics)/Root/group-container[$pos]` and use that.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the below error. 
```Error 1 at line 32:75 : For attribute 'tunnel' within an xsl:apply-templates parameter, the only permitted value is 'no'
Error 2 at line 31:61 : Invalid element <xsl:param> within xsl:apply-templates
Error 3 at line 32:75 : xsl:param must be immediately within a template, function or stylesheet```

Comment: And is it required to pass param from inside ```<xsl:template match="group-container" mode="second-level">``` or  ```<xsl:template match="group-container" mode="first-level">```?

Comment: @user2628187, sorry, I used the wrong `xsl:param` inside of `xsl:apply-templates`, to pass the parameter you need `xsl:with-param`.

Comment: @user2628187, as for your question in the second comment, I am not quite sure whether it ask about whether you need to pass a parameter or are looking for alternatives, or whether you want to know from which template to pass it on.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="en-root" select="document($path-to-en-xml)/Root" />
    <!-- first-level -->
    <div class="first-level-inner">
        <xsl:for-each select="group-container">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <div>
                <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.{$en-root/group-container[$i]/group-name}">
                    <span>
                        <xsl:value-of select="group-name"/>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <!-- second-level -->
    <div class="second-level-inner">
        <xsl:for-each select="group-container/group-title">
            <xsl:variable name="j" select="position()" />
            <h5>
                <xsl:value-of select="title-name"/>
            </h5>
            <span data-webanalytics="menunavigation.{($en-root/group-container/group-title)[$j]/title-name}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the result is an XML fragment, with no single root element.

Comment: I am not Martin Honnen. And I still think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Not sure what that means.